# How to determine which Item on a Listview swiped in Delphi FMX

Tags: listview, delphi, firemonkey, gesture

I would like to swipe Left & right an Item in TListView object in Delphi 11.1 Alexandra.

I did choose Left & Right gestures from the Standard gestures and gesture works fine but I cannot determine which Item exactly swiped.

```
procedure TTest.ListView1Gesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
        Case EventInfo.GestureID of
             sgiLeft  :
                   begin
                       ListView1.Items.Delete(ListView1.Selected.Index);
                   end;
        End;
end;
```

I did try to get by using ListView1.Selected.Index  but unfortunately it is not stable as sometimes gestures comes before the selection event.

I also tried to use ListView1.ItemIndex but no chance.

Please help if you have any idea how to get the Swiped Item index.

Thanks

Comment: The `EventInfo` gives you the coordinates of the swipe. Try querying each visible `TListView` item for its rectangle until you find one that contains the coordinates (see `TListView.GetItemRect()` - I don't see any equivalent of VCL's `TListView.GetItemAt()` or `TListView.GetHitTestInfoAt()` in FMX).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Looks like its working really well. But I check all the items on the listview as I dont know how to check only the ones on the screen.

Comment: [TListView first and last item visible](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/5264-tlistview-first-and-last-item-visible/)

Comment: Thanks a lot again.. It works fantastically well now.

Comment: Which approach from the above link (Provided by @remy Lebeau) did you use?

Comment: Please see my approach as an answer as it it a bit big to put into the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Remy's answer. Please see my approach as below

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Gesture(Sender: TObject;
const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
var
   R: TRectF;
   I: Integer;
   LStartItemIndex, LEndItemIndex : Integer;
begin    

     Case EventInfo.GestureID of
          sgiLeft  :
                    begin
                    //To find out the fist and the last item index of listview items on the screen
                    GetStartEndItemsIndex(ListView1, LStartItemIndex, LEndItemIndex);

                    //To idenfity the the item swiped to left 
                    for I := LStartItemIndex-1 to LEndItemIndex  do
                    begin
                          R := ListView1.GetItemRect(I);

                          if (R.Bottom > EventInfo.Location.Y) and (R.Top < EventInfo.Location.Y) then
                          begin
                              ListView1.Items.Delete(I); break;
                          end;
                    end;
end;

procedure TForm1.GetStartEndItemsIndex(const AListView : TListView; out AStartItemIndex : Integer; out AEndItemIndex : Integer);
var
   LViewportStart, LViewportEnd, LItemAbsEnd : Single;
   LItemIndex : Integer;
begin

   AStartItemIndex := -1;
   AEndItemIndex   := -1;

   LViewportStart := AListView.ScrollViewPos;
   LViewportEnd := AListView.Height + LViewportStart;

   for LItemIndex := 0 to AListView.Items.Count - 1 do
   begin
        LItemAbsEnd := AListView.GetItemRect(LItemIndex).Bottom + AListView.ScrollViewPos;
        if (AStartItemIndex < 0) and (LItemAbsEnd >= LViewportStart) then
        begin
           AStartItemIndex := LItemIndex;
        end;
        if (AStartItemIndex >= 0) and (AEndItemIndex < 0) and (LItemAbsEnd >= LViewportEnd) then
        begin
             AEndItemIndex := LItemIndex;
             Break;
        end;
    end;
    if (AEndItemIndex < 0) and (AListView.Items.Count > 0) then
    begin
       AEndItemIndex := AListView.Items.Count - 1;
    end;
 end;
```